# Incorrect fragments showing android tablayout viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

[image: This is the 3rd screen but the same screen is shown on tab numbered as 2]> I have 4 fragments on "HomeActivity" when I swipe to next fragment new fragment should get displayed What problem I am facing

1. When I swipe for the first time my second tab shows the fragment which is to be shown under the 3rd tab and the 3rd tab shows the correct expected fragment
2. But when I reach the fourth fragment I swipe back it shows expected correct fragments for 2nd and 3rd tab
3. There is inconsistent behavior between 2nd and 3rd tab as sometimes the fragment which is to be shown under 3rd tab gets displayed under the 2nd tab
4. So Main issue is with the 2nd tab which shows 3rd tabs fragment
5. I have tried all the solutions on StackOverflow but none of them worked for me

> Please check below code snippets for reference

ViewPageAdapter.java

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

public void addFragment( Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}}
```

HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TabLayout tabLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("PERSONAL INFORMATION");
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            //1 PERSONAL INFORMATION
            //2 PROFESSIONAL INFORMATION
            //3 FINANCIAL INFORMATION
            //4 DOCUMENT DETAILS
            if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("PERSONAL INFORMATION");
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("PROFESSIONAL INFORMATION");
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("FINANCIAL INFORMATION");
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 3) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("DOCUMENT DETAILS");
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
}


private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(AssignedCustomerFragment.getInstance(), getResources().getString(R.string.assigned_tab));
    adapter.addFragment(CompletedCustomerFragment.getInstance(), getResources().getString(R.string.completed_tab));
    adapter.addFragment(FinancialDetailsFragment.getInstance(), getResources().getString(R.string.finance_info_tab));
    adapter.addFragment(CustomerDocumentFragment.getInstance(), getResources().getString(R.string.document_info_tab));
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return (true);
    }
    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}}
```

Fragment2 code

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_professional_information, container, false);
    final HorizontalScrollView horscroll = (HorizontalScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.horscroll);
    final HorizontalScrollView horscroll1 = (HorizontalScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.horscroll1);
    final HorizontalScrollView horscroll2 = (HorizontalScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.horscroll2);
    final RadioGroup salarieddom = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.rdgsalarieddomain);
    final RadioGroup nonsalarieddom = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.rdgnonsalaried);
    final RadioGroup paymentmode = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.rdgpaymentmode);
    final TextView txtpaymentmode = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtpaymentmode);

    edtcompanyname = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.companyname);
    edtofficialid = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtofficialmailid);
    rdgprofession = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.rdgprof);
    rdgsalariedoption = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.rdgsalarieddomain);
    rdgsalarydrawnthrough = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.rdgpaymentmode);
    rdgnonsalaried = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.rdgnonsalaried);

    rdgprofession.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            switch (i) {
                case R.id.rdbsalaried:
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Salaried", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    salariedornot = "Salaried";
                    break;
                case R.id.rdbnonsalaried:
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Non Salaried", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    salariedornot = "Non Salaried";
                    break;
            }
        }
    });


    rdgsalariedoption.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            switch (i) {
                case R.id.rdbprivate:

                    salarysector = "Private";

                    break;
                case R.id.rdbpublic:

                    salarysector = "Public";

                    break;
                case R.id.rdbgovernment:

                    salarysector = "Government";

                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    rdgsalarydrawnthrough.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            switch (i) {
                case R.id.rdbcash:

                    salarypaymentmode = "Cash";

                    break;
                case R.id.rdbcheque:

                    salarypaymentmode = "Cheque";

                    break;
                case R.id.rdbbanktranfer:

                    salarypaymentmode = "Direct Bank Transfer";

                    break;

            }
        }
    });


    rdgnonsalaried.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            switch (i) {
                case R.id.rdbselfemployed:

                    salarysector = "Self employed";

                    break;
                case R.id.rdbbusiness:

                    salarysector = "Business";

                    break;
                case R.id.rdbretired:

                    salarysector = "Retired";

                    break;
                case R.id.rdbstudent:

                    salarysector = "Student";

                    break;
            }
        }
    });


    RadioGroup rdgGender = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.rdgprof);
    rdgGender.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.rdbsalaried:
                    salarieddom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    horscroll1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    horscroll.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    nonsalarieddom.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    horscroll2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    paymentmode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txtpaymentmode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case R.id.rdbnonsalaried:
                    nonsalarieddom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    horscroll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    horscroll1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    salarieddom.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    horscroll2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    paymentmode.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    txtpaymentmode.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

fragment3 code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_financial_details_fragment, container, false);
    final SeekBar seekbarloanamt = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.sbloanamt);
    final EditText edtseekbarval = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtloanamt);

    edtseekbarval.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if(s.length() >0){
                int i = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
                if(i < 5000000) {
                    edtseekbarval.setSelection(edtseekbarval.getText().length());
                    seekbarloanamt.setProgress(i);
                }
            }
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
    });

    seekbarloanamt.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
            edtseekbarval.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: **FYI** `setOnTabSelectedListener` is deprecated

Comment: Sorry, but - Design, design is never changed

Comment: try to change 

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

instead of 

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

Comment: try setting `viewpager.setoffscreenpagelimit(3);` since you have 4 fragments.

Comment: just remove `viewPager.setCurrentItem();` at every tab selection

Comment: Tried all the solutions none of this worked well thanks will have to find another way to do this